# Angular-DataTables custom filter

Tags: angularjs, datatable, datatables, angularjs-filter

I am trying to add a custom filter to **angular-DataTables** with server side processing, which works perfectly with sorting and built in search of datatables.

I was following example [Angular-DataTables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing), to build the server side processing and setup the DataTable,  in searching around i have found some info but haven't been able to make it work.

What i am trying to get is to redraw the table with filtered data once the `checkbox [Player]` has been triggered.

Does anyone know a solution for this or has a working example for this?

have found this example [Custom Table Filter](https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables/issues/123), but it seems it doesn't work either.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="showcase"><div ng-controller="ServerSideProcessingCtrl">
<label><input type="checkbox" id="customFilter" value="player"> Player</label>
<table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="row-border hover"></table>
```

JS part:

```
 'use strict';

    angular.module('showcase', ['datatables'])
            //.controller('ServerSideProcessingCtrl', ServerSideProcessingCtrl);
    .controller('ServerSideProcessingCtrl',["$scope", "DTOptionsBuilder", "DTColumnBuilder", function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {

    //function ServerSideProcessingCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        console.log($scope);
        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
                    // dataSrc: 'data',
                    url: 'getTableData.php',
                    type: 'POST'
                })
            // or here
                .withDataProp('data')
                .withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('First name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('position').withTitle('Position'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('type').withTitle('Type')
        ];

        $scope.$on('event:dataTableLoaded', function(event, loadedDT) {
            console.log(event);
            console.log(loadedDT);
            $('#customFilter').on('change', function() {
                loadedDT.DataTable.draw();
            } );


        });

    }]);
```

JSON on load:

```
{"draw":"1","recordsTotal":8,"recordsFiltered":8,"data":[{"id":"1","name":"Raul","position":"front","type":"player"},{"id":"2","name":"Crespo","position":"front","type":"player"},{"id":"3","name":"Nesta","position":"back","type":"player"},{"id":"4","name":"Costacurta","position":"back","type":"player"},{"id":"5","name":"Doc Brown","position":"staff","type":"medic"},{"id":"6","name":"Jose","position":"staff","type":"manager"},{"id":"7","name":"Ferguson","position":"staff","type":"manager"},{"id":"8","name":"Zinedine","position":"staff","type":"director"}]}
```

Comment: I followed your code. But always its shows all records. No pagination for me. How did you fixed that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and browsing, combined few examples and came up with this.

HTML :

```
 <label><input type="checkbox" id="customFilter" value="player" ng-click="reload()" > Player</label>
```

JS:

```
 'use strict';

    angular.module('showcase', ['datatables'])
            //.controller('ServerSideProcessingCtrl', ServerSideProcessingCtrl);
    .controller('ServerSideProcessingCtrl',["$scope", "DTOptionsBuilder", "DTColumnBuilder","DTInstances",  function ($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, DTInstances) {

    //function ServerSideProcessingCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
        console.log($scope);

        $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                .withOption('ajax', {
                    // Either you specify the AjaxDataProp here
                    // dataSrc: 'data',
                    url: 'getTableData.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    // CUSTOM FILTERS
                    data: function (data) {
                        data.customFilter = $('#customFilter').is(':checked');
                    }
                })
            // or here
                .withDataProp('data')
                .withOption('serverSide', true)
                .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
        $scope.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('name').withTitle('First name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('position').withTitle('Position'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('type').withTitle('Type')
        ];

        DTInstances.getLast().then(function (dtInstance) {
            $scope.dtInstance = dtInstance;
        });

        $scope.reload = function(event, loadedDT) {
            $scope.dtInstance.reloadData();
        };

    }]);
```

and on the backend just go through the $_POST and check for custom filter, hopefully this will help someone

Comment: hey I am trying to use this plugin but getting errors 
DO you have any sample live page 
where I can find where I am missing

Answer (score 0):

You can use **withFnServerData** with **fromSource** functions instead of
**withOption**:

> This API allows you to override the default function to retrieve the data (which is `$.getJSON` according to DataTables documentation) to something more suitable for you application.
>
> It's mainly used for Datatables v1.9.4. See [DataTable documentation](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks#fnServerData).

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
    .withFnServerData(serverData);

function serverData (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
    oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
        'dataType': 'json',
        'type': 'POST',
        'url': sSource,
        'data': aoData,
        'success': fnCallback
    });
```

---

:)

Answer (score 0):

Ok sorry its not a full blown example. This only works with *angular* and *datatables*, if you do a filter on the `ng-repeat eg | aFilter:this`  The `this` transfers the scope. The filtering applied can now be quite complex. Within the n`g-controller` `<div>` you can have an html partial containing drop downs or input texts, all having an `ng-model` value.

When these change they kick off the filter routine`aFilter` an `angular.filter('aFilter'....` js routine. The records are piped through the afilter routine allowing the ones wanted to be pushed onto an array and this is what is returned with the return. It doesn't work with breeze, yet. Be aware it is unlikely to be server side. To deal with server side maybe an SQL call in the service....another day.

eg in the `ng-table id="test"` :

```
<tr ng-repeat="edRec in aSetOfJSonRecords | aFilter:this | orderBy:'summat'">
{{edRec.enCode}} etc
</tr>
```

in the `aFilter`, the `fltEnCode` represents the `ng-model` values, the test variable allows freedom from nulls causing issues upon comparison, good idea to test for undefined first:

```
   app.filter('aFilter', [function () {
        return function (items, $scope) {

            var countItems = 0;
            var filtered = [];
            var isOK = 0;

            angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                isOK = 1;
                // some conditions
                if ($scope.fltEnCode !== "") {
                    if (item.enCode === null) { test = ""; } else { test = item.enCode; }
                if (test.indexOf($scope.fltEnCode) < 0) isOK = 0;
                }
                // end of conditions
                if (isOK > 0) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                    countItems++;
                }
            });
           // alert(countItems);
            return filtered;
        };
    }]);
```

Hope its of some use. I've avoided boolean variables as they have given grief before. Odd occasions have needed an `ng-change` in the html items pointing to an angular function resetting the data by calling the `getTheItemsForTest()` in the controller. This redraws the list. Having

```
$scope.dtOptions = {
     stateSave: false, .......
```

in your controller, keeps the sorting columns correct.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#test').DataTable();
    table.draw();
};
```

might also be useful if its recalcitrant. I need to know how to make it work for breeze??? Enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

here is what I really missed after I searched alot

bower install datatables-light-columnfilter